# Cannot create Site Collection and access sitecollections

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, site-collection, web-application, ssl

I tried to configure SSL in my SharePoint Server 2013 test environment. I didnt succeed and now i cannot access any of my sites, create new sitecollections or web applications. Even the ones that used to work on http cannot be accessed. I get the message: "Sorry, something went wrong" on my http sites. I can still access my central administration site.

I have tried to Disable loopbackcheck(http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx) and been searching the web for a solution, but i cant for the life of me figure out what is wrong!

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: could you please explain, what steps you perform to configure SSL?

Comment: I used this guide: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fabdulwahab/2013/01/20/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: How many web applications did you do this for? Did you use the same certificate for more than one web application?